# jenkins does not recognize checkstyle and pmd reports generated by sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am using sonar to generate Findbugs, Checkstyle and PMD reports, then feeding those reports to jenkins to generate graphs based on the xml files, but i get the following error on jenkins.

```
[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing of file /home/bldarea/.../checkstyle.xml failed due to an exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Input stream is not a Checkstyle file.
at hudson.plugins.checkstyle.parser.CheckStyleParser.parse(CheckStyleParser.java:69)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractAnnotationParser.parse(AbstractAnnotationParser.java:53)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFile(FilesParser.java:306)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFiles(FilesParser.java:264)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parserCollectionOfFiles(FilesParser.java:215)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:184)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:31)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2246)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

and similarly for PMD files

```
[PMD] Parsing of file /home/bldarea/.../pmd.xml failed due to an exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Input stream is not a PMD file.
at hudson.plugins.pmd.parser.PmdParser.parse(PmdParser.java:72)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractAnnotationParser.parse(AbstractAnnotationParser.java:53)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFile(FilesParser.java:306)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFiles(FilesParser.java:264)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parserCollectionOfFiles(FilesParser.java:215)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:184)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:31)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2246)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be sure that the Jenkins plugins use the same version of Checkstyle & PMD than the ones that are embedded in Sonar. So I'm not surprised that such issues can occur.

By the way: I don't see the point to display those results in Jenkins. Sonar UI is far more advanced for quality stuff.

Comment: Ok....Actually i have to show the findbugs, checkstyle and PMD reports in graphical view, please can you guide me how to achieve it on sonar. I could successfully generate reports but could create a graphical view. please can you help me to do so.

Comment: Well, it's useless to have a chart that shows violations per rule engine: what's the point? A violation is a vioaltion, may it be generated by Findbugs or PMD! If you want to have charts, you can add widgets like what you can see on http://nemo.sonarsource.org.

Answer (score 0):

The files you've mentioned doesn't seems like the output reports. Rather they are the rule configuration files. For instance, the PMD report file should not be pmd.xml, rather it should be pmd-results.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Refer {https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26638?focusedCommentId=220317&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-220317}
Similar issue raised in Jenkin's defect tracking tool. It might help.

I was facing similar issue for PMD [failed due to an exception: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Input stream is not a PMD file.]
As per JIRA ticket(given above) followed below steps,

- Using Maven, executed project in eclipse first.
- So, PMD created its own pmd.xml file based my file.
- Replaced PMD.xml generated by me with one generated by PMD.
- imported pmd generated pmd.xml in jenkin
- built project and issue got resolved.

[jenkins](/questions/tagged/jenkins) [pmd](/questions/tagged/pmd)